# How to populate width of a button to another button (no using weight)

Tags: android, button

I'd like to make the same width for all buttons in vertical layout,
which is equal to the button with maximum text.
I try to get the width of button with max text.
The following does not work.
There are many questions about it in this site.

```
width=button1.getWidth();
button2.setWidth(width);
```

Okay, I can get button1.getWidth() as described
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595315/getwidth-returns-0-in-fragment-getpaddingleft-returns-non-zero/11595439#11595439)

But I can't find an answer how to set new width to other buttons.
I can't set the width to button2.

"int width" should be final. If I make it final, I got error
for width=button1.getWidth().

Any ideas please?
Thanks!!!

---

MY CODE AFTER MODIFICATIONS.
As I said it changes button2 width only once.
When I return to page1 again, the width of button2 is not changed.

```
Button button1;
Button button2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    page1();
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    widthButton=button1.getWidth();
    if (widthButtons==0) return;
    LayoutParams lp = button2.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = widthButton;
    button2.setLayoutParams(lp);
}

private void page1() {
    button1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            page2();
        }
    });

    button2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);

}
private void page2() {
    Button button5 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            page1();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No, this is another question.

Comment: Try this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295293/give-all-child-elements-fixed-width-in-android/25296962#25296962

Comment: Thank you, but there no answer. Tablelayout does not guarantee that text in button will not be wrapped. As for getChildAt, there are not code example. And it looks it is not my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `TableLayout` [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295293/give-all-child-elements-fixed-width-in-android/25296962#25296962) and then prevent the text in the buttons from wrapping by adding to the XML for each button `android:maxLines="1"`

Using the right layout manager is more reliable than trying to change view sizes by hand.

Comment: Thank you, but TableLayout does not guarantee text from wrapping, if android:maxLines="1", then as I think, text can be shorten.

Comment: Yes!!! It works! Thank you. This is the most simple solution for this question. Thank you! I 've switched the best answer to your answer. But MHP's approach also works. Sorry, I have not enough reputation to vote for MHP.

Answer (score 0):

you should do this to set width for you button.

```
  int width = button1.getWidth();
  LayoutParams lp = button2.getLayOutParams();
  lp.width = width;
  button2.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

NOTE: do this in onWindowFocusChange() method,because before that your views was not created

UPDATE: this work for me

```
private int widthButton = 0;
private Button button1;
private Button button2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    widthButton=button1.getWidth();
    if (widthButton==0) return;
    LayoutParams lp = button2.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = widthButton;
    button2.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

UPDATE:
  change page1() and page2() to this:

```
private void page1() {
    setContentView(R.layout.page_1);
    button1a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1a);
    button1a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            page2();
        }
    });

    button1b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1b);

    LayoutParams lp = button1b.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = width;
    button1b.setLayoutParams(lp);
}

private void page2() {
    setContentView(R.layout.page_2);
    button2a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2a);
    button2a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            page1();
        }
    });

    button2b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2b);

    LayoutParams lp = button1b.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = width;
    button2b.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

NOTE: your code works perfectly but it isn't true code. if you want to change view of your activity you should use fragment.

Comment: Wow! It works. Thank you very much!  But when I run this page again, I see the old width for button2. Each page runs another from OnCreate().

Comment: Adding/deleting the line "super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);" does not change the performance.

Comment: onwindowfocuschange should call when you run activity,so if you settwidth in that method it should work

Comment: To show buttons I call page1() from onCreate. Now buttons view are as expected. Then in page1() I call page2() after clicking some button. In page2() I call page1() again. And now the width of button1 is not populated to button2

Comment: ok,first I should say don't need to start activity from page2,just call finish().second normally onWindowFocusChange() call after each time you visit activity but i saw in some device it's different,so you can store button1 width first time and in onresume() set width for button2 or do some thing like @user3249477 answer if it not work ,call me

Comment: Sorry, not understood. I call all page1, page2,... in the same activity. Button1.post does not work. Maybe I have to place his code in another place than in page1(). Thanks.

Comment: I am chaking your project but at first you should change button1 and button2 as global variable not in method page1 and page2

Comment: Oh, pardon. They are global. I am mistaken writing the program schema here

Comment: code work for me,I don't know where is your problem.I can help you if you want by sending me your project(by email)

Comment: I expected that it is easy to populate width of one button to another. But it seems it is not so easy. Do you think such approach makes sense? Margins or weight for vertical layouts looks much more easy. Okay, I will send the project. It is interesting anyway. Thanks!

Comment: My page1 and page2 in the same activity. But they are in different activities in your code. It seems it the reason that my code does not work properly. But having special activity for each page looks me cumbersome. Or my approach is incorrect?

Comment: TableLayout solution below looks me more simple. Sorry, MHP, I have not enough reputation to vote for you, since your approach also works. Thanks again for participation!

Comment: @Niaz ,there is multiple way that I told you,like fragment that is best way instead change setcontentview or viewSwitcher or viewpager or... I learn new one from x-code too.but I try to help you as you like it to do. also I help you because we are from same country,and I want to improve you. no problem at all :)

Comment: MHP, thank you for help. But it seems the country of user is not visible here. Maybe I don't understand something in this site...

Comment: from your name I understand

Comment: My name is popular in many countries. There are countries where are few or many  native nations.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are trying to `getWidth()` of `button1` when it wasn't yet drawn. Instead add it to the queue with `post()`:

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

button1.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int width = button1.getWidth();
        button2.setWidth(width);
    }
});
```

The reason why setWidth(0) made it look like nothing has changed, is because the Button has a min width of *64dip* :)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. (onWindowFocusChanged block is removed)

Comment: @Niaz are you not getting the correct width or setting the width doesn't work?

Comment: I placed your code in page1(), which is called from onCreate(). The width of button2 was not changed. Thanks!